# ASP.NET emergency shutdown and redirect

Tags: asp.net, shutdown

I was told that to shutdown an ASP.NET site and replace all pages with a static text one should add an HTML file with a special extension. But my google/bing skills are not good enough, can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Create an "app_offline.htm" file and place it in the main directory of the application/website.

http://asp-net-whidbey.blogspot.com/2006/04/aspnet-20-features-appofflinehtm.html

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx

You can put whatever HTML content you want in the .htm file and any request to your application will display this file.

Note [Mehmet Ergut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111511/mehmet-ergut)'s comment:

"The file size should be at least 512 bytes, or Internet Exploser won't display the contents." 
– [Mehmet Ergut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111511/mehmet-ergut)

Comment: The file size should be at least 512 bytes, or Internet Exploser won't display the contents.

Comment: Thanks guys, app_offline.htm did the job.